# Scrollers in uiwebview

Tags: ios4, ios-simulator, iphone

I have a webview. I have enabled the scrolling feature of the webview. The scrollers are displayed when I scroll the webview.

But I need to show the scrollbar even if I am not scrolling to indicate that a scroll is possible in this view.

Is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

well, probably it's not possible, but if your purpose is just to let users know it's a scrollable view you can just let them see it when you load your webPages, forcing webContent to scroll to top from position.y + 100 to top. you gan get the UIScrollView used by your UIWebView and scroll it...

in your UIViewController just add this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)wwwebView {
    UIScrollView *myUIWebScrollView = (UIScrollView*)[wwwebView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    [myUIWebScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 100) animated:NO];
    [self performSelector:@selector(scrollUp:) withObject:wwwebView afterDelay:0.4];
}

- (void)scrollUp:(UIWebView*)aWebView{
    UIScrollView *myUIWebScrollView = (UIScrollView*)[aWebView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    [myUIWebScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];

}
```

your UIViewController must be a UIWebViewDelegate so add  in .h file:

```
    @interface yourWebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {

    }

- (void)scrollUp:(UIWebView*)aWebView;
```

Comment: @dsc: sure... not for you? you must put it in the UIViewController which load and control the view with the UIWebView... and as i said it must me a UIWebViewDelegate... maybe you didn't set the delegate property of your UIWebView when you allocated and added to subView: code:  yourWebView.delegate = self;

Comment: I had added the <UIWbViewDelegate> in the .h file also in the .xib file I had set the delegate instead of yourWebView.delegate = self;

Comment: @dsc: then - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView; should be called by default every time a new page is loaded in the UIWebView... put a NSLog(@"i'm here!"); to check it... if it's not called (as other method of UIWebViewDelegate...) then there's something wrong somewhere else (delegating link...?), not in the code itself... take a look at UIWebViewDelegate protocol reference in xCode help...

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not possible to force the scroolbars to show because it's part of the apple's user experience philosophy.